# Using java, json, ajax and html to display image/name pairs in a row - currently displays in a column

Tags: java, html, json, ajax

I am trying to display some images with their names below them using json. I want the image/name pairs to be next to each other. At the moment they are one under the other.

HTML:

```
    <form data-toggle="validator" role="form" id="selectForm">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-select">
                    <!-- Place for Captcha image -->
                    <div class="input-group" id="img-container">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /row -->
    </form>
```

ajax:

```
.done(function(responseJson1a) {
    dataType: "json";
    //Remove existing images
    $("#img-container").find("img").remove();

    // JSON response to populate the image
    $(responseJson1a).appendTo($("#img-container"));

    for (i = 0; i < responseJson1a.length; i++) {
        $(responseJson1a[i]).appendTo($("#img-container"));
    }
});
```

java:

```
        String json = null;
        int i = 0;
        for (final YouthMember youthMember : youthMembers) {
            String image = youthMember.getPhotograph();
            String name = youthMember.getFirstname();
            if (i == 0){
                json = "<div class='input-group'> <img src=" + image + " width='60' alt='captcha image' > " + 
                        "<h3 class='form-line-heading'>" + name + "</h3> </div>";
                i++;
            }else{
                json = json + ("<img src=" + image + " width='60' alt='captcha image' >" +
                        "<h3 class='form-line-heading'>" + name + "</h3> </div>");
            }
        }
```

I have tried placing the "" at the end encapsulating all the images; however, that does not work (image/string pairs are still in a single column.

When I remove the names "" + name + "" and the opening "" the images are one after the other in a row until the row is filled and then start a new row. This is what I want except with the names under each image.

Changed to (including style='display:inline;') - now images and names are all inline. Want name under image:

```
for (final YouthMember youthMember : youthMembers) {
            String image = youthMember.getPhotograph();
            String name = youthMember.getFirstname();
            if (i == 0){
                json = "<div class='input-group'> <img src=" + image + " width='60' alt='captcha image' > " + 
                        "<h4 class='form-line-heading' style='display:inline;'>" + name + "</h4>";
                i++;
            }else{
                json = json + ("<img src=" + image + " width='60' alt='captcha image' >" +
                        "<h4 class='form-line-heading' style='display:inline;'>" + name + "</h4>");
            }
        }
        json = json + "</div>";
```

This change has mostly worked (issue with 19th image):

```
    String json = null;
    int i = 0;
    for (final YouthMember youthMember : youthMembers) {
        String image = youthMember.getPhotograph();
        String name = youthMember.getFirstname();
        if (i == 0){
            json = "<div class='col-md-2'> <img src=" + image + " width='60' alt='captcha image' > " + 
                    "<h4 class='form-line-heading'>" + name + "</h4></div>";
            i++;
        }else{
            json = json + ("<div class='col-md-2'> <img src=" + image + " width='60' alt='captcha image' >" +
                    "<h4 class='form-line-heading'>" + name + "</h4></div>");
        }
    }
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(json);
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following style for `<h3>`:

```
 style="display:inline;"
```

> Edit:

I guess you are using bootstrap, so better if you wrap both `img` and `h4` into another div like so:

```
<div class="row">
 <!-- your img and h4 go here -->
</div>
```

If not using bootstrap then `<br/>` should be enough after every `<h4>`

Or better to have `<div class='input-group'></div>` for each `img`&`h4`.

Comment: Almost, that puts the name after the image instead of under. However, now inline (e.g., image, name, image, name, image, name).

Comment: Sorry, this has name next to image in a column. I edited above.

Comment: Based on your last edit: change class='row' with class='col-md-2'. Also, remove style='display:inline;' from h4. Initially, I misunderstood your question (((

Comment: Please see edit. Almost there, issue with 19th image on its own line. Also when I resize and go to six images across the sixth row has two images and when I go under six across all images are in one column.

Comment: (i.e., I can not go six, five, four, three, two, one across - it is six then one image across).

Comment: Thanks Zhavat for your help. I do not think this will go much further so I will accept your answer and ask another question relating to the formatting.